# How should I mix JSP, servlets, and HTML?

Tags: jsp, servlets, jstl

I'm working on some web pages. I created form by JSP/JSTL/servlet.

I have HTML, CSS, and JavaScript files on disk. My goal is add JSTL form to HTML page which consist some frame and import CSS, JavaScript files.

I try add HTML code to my JSP but it isn´t good idea.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, where to put specific elements? Where HTML should be generated?

Answer (score 1):

On the contrary - your html must go in the JSP. It should be mixed with JSTL there. Everything else (java code) should go in servlets. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files/3180202#3180202) for more details.

Typically a page looks like this:

```
<html>
   <head><title><fmt:message key="title" /></title></head>
   <body>
       <c:forEach items="${results}" var="result">
           <h2>${result.title}</h2>
           <p style="margin-top: 10px;">${result.text}</p>
       </c:forEach>
   </body>
</html>
```